# Callback from JQuery-UI to Angular 6

Tags: angular, jquery-ui

I added the JQuery-UI [MonthPicker](https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/) to my Angular 6 application.
I want to trigger an Angular action when my date changes:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myMonthPicker').MonthPicker(
        {
          Button: false,
          MaxMonth: -1,
          MonthFormat: 'MM yy'
          OnAfterChooseMonth: this.update()
        }
      );
    });
  }

  update() {
    alert('works');
  }
```

The update method is never hit.
And I have the following error:

> TypeError: this.update is not a function

How could I call an Angular method from my JQuery-UI code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `this` scope has been lost by using `function() {}`, try:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const update = this.update();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myMonthPicker').MonthPicker(
      {
        Button: false,
        MaxMonth: -1,
        MonthFormat: 'MM yy'
        OnAfterChooseMonth: update
      }
    );
  });
}
```

---

Or change your function to ES6 arrow notation:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  ...
});
```

*Note: This generally fixes this problem, but I'm not how jQuery UI handles it. Can't guarantee this will work*

Comment: Thanks, using the ES6 arrow notation allows me to call `this.update`